# How to run spark standalone cluster on pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to run a python script that reads data from MongoDB and then uses them for analysis purpose by pyspark. I have been able to run my code with just the driver but I have problems when adding workers.

Following Spark official documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) I started master (port 8080) and woker (port 8081) node then i tried to:

```
spark-shell --master spark://<host>:<port>
```

and everything works fine, since i get a cluster and not just the driver.

Then I tried to use this cluster (on port 4040) by my pyspark script:

```
my_spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master("spark://<host>:<port>")\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", input_uri)\
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", output_uri)\
    .config('spark.jars.packages','org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.2.2')\
    .getOrCreate()
```

but it try creating a new port (4041) failing with the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
  File "/MongoDB/TestSpark.py", line 84, in <module>
    .getOrCreate()
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I want to call the cluster I have already created on port 4040. Is there a way?

By the way I'm working on a docker container, if that has any relevance.